# How do I access the trained Spacy Thinc model?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, spacy-3

I'm trying to access the trained neural network model used by the spaCy pipeline.

I can see from the spaCy documentation that the config.cfg specifies the model instance which is part of the pipeline, but I don’t understand how to access this model instance (data structure or its location) from within spaCy.

[image: spaCy documentation]

I'd like to access the model and its weights so I can use the neural network outside of spaCy. I was wondering if anyone had any pointers for accessing the Thinc pre-trained model?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/explosion/thinc

Comment: Thanks @tauft I've had a look through the Thinc api but where I'm struggling is where/how to access the model instance used by the spaCy pipeline. I'm not sure where/how it's stored.

Comment: If your goal is to use the model outside of spacy, doesn't the thinc api let you do that?

Comment: Hopefully yes, but I’m not sure where the model is stored (which data structure or location) in spacy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Model of a component like this.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
model = ner.model
```

By convention, each component keeps its model (if present) in `self.model`.

I'm not sure the model will be useful to you on its own though - models generally depend on the tok2vec they were with, and the tok2vec depends on the representation of lexemes in spaCy.  So without the other parts of the pipeline you probably won't be able to get meaningful predictions.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you know if you can access these other components from the pipe in the same way? Also is there a reference in the api for this? I can see get_pipe but nothing which details the pipeline components which can be accessed.

Comment: You can use `nlp.pipe_names` to get the pipe names. `get_pipe` works for any component. https://spacy.io/api/language#attributes